# triangular_numbers enumerator yielder yield

Tags: ruby, yield, enumerator

```
 triangular_numbers = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
 number = 0
 count = 1
     loop do
         number += count
         count += 1
         yielder.yield number
     end
 end
 5.times { print triangular_numbers.next, " " }
 puts
```

I know you all have answers questions about this before.

I am trying to understand more about what going on

Am I right to say **yielder** is a parameter which is probably a hash or an array and
**yielder.yield number** is basically pushing whatever number it is on to that array.

Also I seen people use yielder << number, i assume that you can also use
yielder.push(number), will it do the same thing.

One other thing I like to know why the  **number** is retaining its value.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a data structure. It's an object - an instance of [`Enumerator::Yielder`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator/Yielder.html) which, if you click the link, you will see isn't documented very well! It is written in C, and the only methods it has are `yield` and the alias `<<`. You should leave it to the Ruby core to handle itself.

It's essentially like a *pipe*, which is used internally by the [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) and [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) methods to fetch items from an enumeration as required. `Enumerator#next`, for example, will fetch the next item from the sequence. The methods available in `Enumerable` are much more comprehensive, and are based on the basic operations provided by `Enumerator`.